# update_column updates my instance.xxxable but not the instance itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure this is because I'm using Rails 4 but I'm puzzled.

```
I have the following models set:

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stars, :as => :starable, :dependent => :destroy 
  belongs_to :user
end

class Star < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_to_total_stars

  belongs_to :starable, :polymorphic => true

  protected

  def add_to_total_stars
    if [Post].include?(starable.class)
      self.starable.update_column(:total_stars, starable.total_stars + self.number)
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So I created a star and a post in the Rails console:

```
star = post.stars.build number: 2
post = Post.create title: "test", content: "test", user_id: 1
```

Then used the following to modify the `average_stars` column in `post`:

```
star.starable.update(:average_stars, 4)
```

Everything OK so far:

```
star.starable
 => #<Post id: 9, title: "test", content: "test", created_at: "2013-07-25 16:05:52", updated_at: "2013-07-25 16:05:52", user_id: 1, average_stars: 4, total_stars: 0.0>
```

But then I wanted to check `post` and I saw this:

```
 post
 => #<Post id: 9, title: "test", content: "test", created_at: "2013-07-25 16:05:52", updated_at: "2013-07-25 16:05:52", user_id: 1, average_stars: 0, total_stars: 0.0>
```

`average_stars` wasn't updated at all.

Why is update_column updating star.starable but not the post?

Comment: Have you got your post and star creation the right way round? From what you have described, star and post are not linked at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not wrong. Your `star` and `post` objects are now just in memory. You changed the DB data for `post`, but your`post` object in memory doesn't automatically reconnect to the database to update its internal data. You'd have to do `post.reload` to do that, manually.

Depending on the context of your code, this may be perfectly fine.

Also, unless you're really, really, really trying to improve upon performance, the `average_stars` shouldn't be an attribute/column, but rather a *derived* attribute that you can calculate dynamically when you need it.

**EDIT** Regarding making a derived attribute, what I mean is that you would make a method for it. Currently it's a column in your database, so you can do things like:

```
Post.first.average_stars # => 4
```

Instead, make a method named `average_stars` in your `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def average_stars
     # calculate
     return the_result
  end
end
```

And then you can call this method in the same way as before, but instead of just grabbing it from the database, it's being calculated. You can [memoize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/memoize) this so for the life time of your object it won't have to recalculate it (unless you force it to) but be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How to I create a *derived* attribute? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought you were talking of scopes.